# Searching from a list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to search from a list in python. Whenever I input the search term it always say "No tweets contained *search*", even when I know that the term is in the list. What am I doing wrong?

```
elif(ch==3):
        match = 0
        tweetlist.reverse()
        if tweetlist == []:
            print("There are no tweets to search.\n")
            continue
        else:
            search = input("What would you like to search for? ")
            for tweets in tweetlist:
                if(search in tweetlist):
                    match = 1
                if match == 1:
                    print ("Search Results")
                    print("----------")
                    print(tweets.get_author(), "-", tweets.get_age())
                    print(tweets.get_text(), "\n")
                elif match == 0:
                    print("No tweets contained,", search, "\n")
```

Comment: Could be a bad copy/paste but "if match == 1:" should is indented too far

Comment: Do you want to search for a text that contains the specified 'search' criteria? Or you want to search in general for all the occurrences (author,age etc) ? 
if search in tweets.get_text():
   match = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ...
 matched_tweets = []
 if search in tweets.get_text(): 
     match = 1
     matched_tweets.append(tweets) # append all the matches to an array
 ...

 # to print out the results
 for tweet in matched_tweets:
     print(tweet.get_text(), "\n")
```

Comment: This works. However, I think I am needing to return all search results with the search term. This only returns 1 result. I think this may have to do with me setting match = 1. What can I do to fix this?